# Linq subquery or where cause

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to do something like this with `LINQ`:

```
select t1.vendor, t1.location 
from t1, t2
where t1.vendor = t2.vendor and t1.location = t2.location
```

But t2 is not a table, it is a `data filter object` I am thinking to create to contain the data like the following.

```
  ┌──────────┬───────────┬
  │  Vendor  |  location │
  ├──────────┬───────────|
  |    v1    |     100   |
  |    v1    |     102   |
  |    v1    |     103   |
  |    v2    |     100   |
  |    v3    |     203   |
  ├──────────────────────┼
```

My question is: what is the best data structure to contain these filter data and use it to query the table t1 from `SQL Server`? Since vendor to location is one to many relationship, I could not use dictionary or hash table. `NameValueCollection` is not generic type.
In addition, how the `LINQ` syntax should look like to retrieve the data from `SQL Server`? Please help!

Thank you!
Wendy

Comment: you can use a `Tuple<string,int>`

Comment: I don't think I can use tuple because tuple only store one single row of data, right? Sorry I have not use tuple before. I also can not use it to join my t1 table, I assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use anonymous type for your t2;
Something like this:

```
var t2 = from xx in context.SomeTable
select new {Vendor = xx.v, Location = xx.l};
```

Then you can use t2 in your next query.

Example:

```
var result = from t1 in context.T1
              from tt in t2
              where t1.vendor = tt.vendor && t1.location = tt.location 
             select new {t1.vendor, t1.location }
```

Or you can join t1 and t2